# Python: Reading Data from Multiple CSV Files to Lists

Tags: python, arrays, list, csv, multidimensional-array

I'm using Python 3.5 to move through directories and subdirectories to access csv files and fill arrays with data from those files. The first csv file the code encounters looks like this:

[image: csv data file]

The code I have is below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os, csv, datetime, time, glob

gpheight = []
RH = []
dewpt = []
temp = []
windspd = []
winddir = []

dirpath, dirnames, filenames = next(os.walk('/strm1/serino/DATA'))

count2 = 0
for dirname in dirnames:
    if len(dirname) >= 8:
        try:
            dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(dirname[:8], '%m%d%Y')
            csv_folder = os.path.join(dirpath, dirname)
            for csv_file2 in glob.glob(os.path.join(csv_folder, 'figs', '0*.csv')):
                if os.stat(csv_file2).st_size == 0:
                    continue
                #create new arrays for each case
                gpheight.append([])
                RH.append([])
                temp.append([])
                dewpt.append([])
                windspd.append([])
                winddir.append([])
                with open(csv_file2, newline='') as f2_input:
                    csv_input2 = csv.reader(f2_input,delimiter='    ')
                    for j,row2 in enumerate(csv_input2):
                        if j == 0:
                            continue #skip header row
                        #fill arrays created above
                        windspd[count2].append(float(row2[5]))
                        winddir[count2].append(float(row2[6]))
                        gpheight[count2].append(float(row2[1]))
                        RH[count2].append(float(row2[4]))
                        temp[count2].append(float(row2[2]))
                        dewpt[count2].append(float(row2[3]))
                count2 = count2 + 1
        except ValueError as e:
            pass
```

I have it set up to create a new array for each new csv file.  However, when I print the third (temperature) column,

```
for n in range(0,len(temp)):
    print(temp[0][n])
```

it only partially prints that column of data:

```
-70.949997
-68.149994
-60.449997
-63.649994
-57.449997
-51.049988
-45.349991
-40.249985
-35.549988
-31.249985
-27.149994
-24.549988
-22.149994
-19.449997
-16.349976
-13.25
-11.049988
-8.949982
-6.75
-4.449982
-2.25
-0.049988
```

In addition, I believe a related problem is that when I simply do,

```
print(temp)
```

it prints [image: full temp]

with the highlighted section the section that belongs to this one csv file, and should therefore be in one array.  There are also additional empty arrays at the end that should not be there.

I have (not shown) a section of code before this that does the same thing but with different csv files, and that works as expected, separating each file's data into a new array, with no empty arrays.  I appreciate any help!

Comment: At least first prob can be solved by changing len(temp) to len(temp[0]) in for loop :-P

Comment: Thank you, @AbhishekJebaraj, that does help a bit! It's usually difficult for me to work with multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: I found the problem, but I'll take the time to provide an answer later.

Comment: Yes please do.. thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue had been my use of `try` and `pass`.  All the files that matched my criteria were met, but some of those files had issues with how their contents were read, which caused the errors I was receiving later in the code.  For anyone looking to use `try` and `pass`, make sure that you are able to safely pass on any exceptions that block of code may encounter.  Otherwise, it could cause problems later.  You may still get an error if you don't pass on it, but that will force you to fix it appropriately instead of ignoring it.